# how to get city by selected country using mysql in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i want to get cities of selected country i create one table of location with id,country and cities and get country through Json

```
 var items="";


    $.getJSON("get-data.php",function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {
          items+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.country+"</option>";
        });

        $("#class_id").html(items); 
      });

        $('select').on('change', function() {
         a=this.value;
        });
```

now i want to select cities when country is selected..

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
 $conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Can't Connect With Local");
mysql_select_db('f_o_r',$conn) or die("Local DB Not Found");
$q = "SELECT  DISTINCT country FROM location";
$sql = mysql_query($q) or die("query failed");
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, true)){
    $data[] = $row; 
}
echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

Comment: Select * FROM cities WHERE country='$country'

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your values as follows:

```
$.getJSON("get-data.php",function(data){
    $.each(data,function(index,item) 
    {
        $("#country_id").append('<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.country+'</option>'); // It will append all values
    }
}
```

And after selecting this you can select states on select of country list as follows:
Use post for this:

```
$("#country_id").change(function()
{
   $.post('getstate.php',{country_id:$("#country_id").val()},function(data)
   {
       for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
       {
          $("#state_id").append('<option value="'+data[i].state_id+'">'+data[i].state_name+'</option>'); // It will append all values
       }
   });
});
```

And in getstate.php write the code to get states based on `$_POST['country_id']`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add column **level** to table **location** for remark the location type.

```
exp: 
0 => country
1 => city
2 => ...
```

and your api may need to change:

```
[params]

parent_id: the parent id
level:     look for level

[exp]

   url: get-data.php?parent_id=6&level=1
   then you may get US(id equal 6)'s all cities
```

your js need add **change listener** on country, when it is changed send a ajax to like

```
$('#country_id').change(function(){
    $.post('get-data.php',{parent_id:$('#country_id').val(),level:1},function(data){
       console.log(data);
       //get your data cities do want you want
    });
});
```

> get-data.php => router /xxx/location method GET more **restful**

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to relate cities with country. add this code after removing $data = []

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, true)){
$data1['country'] = $row['country'];
$citysql = "SELECT cities from location where country = '".$row['country']."'";
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($citysql,true))
{
 array_push($data1['cities'],$row1['cities']);
}
array_push($data,array($data1['country'],$data1['cities'])); 
}
```